# How to append contents of multiple files into one file?

Tags: files

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10, Dired+

How to append contents of multiple files in one folder into one file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that appends the contents of each file under DIR and writes the results into a result.txt file in the same directory.

```el
(defun append-file-contents (dir)
  (interactive "DDirectory: ")
  (let (contents
        (default-directory dir)
        (files (directory-files dir nil "^\\([^#.~]\\)")))
    (dolist (file files)
      (when (file-regular-p file)
        (push (with-temp-buffer
                (insert-file-contents file)
                (buffer-string))
              contents)))
    (write-region (mapconcat #'identity contents "\n")
                   nil (concat dir "result.txt"))))
```

Comment: In folder has 50 text files. Every file with size 5MB. Is this function "append-file-contents" success process all this files?

Comment: Can you modify your function to be "interactive" with param dir path? And store result to file,e.g. result.txt. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. See if that works for you. Maybe try with some test files first.

Comment: Would you like to re-indent the code so that it'll be more readable?

Comment: @jagrg is it possible to append text of all files not only in current dir, but also in all subfolders?

Comment: @Alexei try with `directory-files-recursively` instead of `directory-files` and see if that works.

Comment: @jagrg directory-files-recursively: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Comment: @Alexei the arguments are not the same, so change it to `(directory-files-recursively dir ".")`. Also, the line `(default-directory dir)` is probably not needed.

Comment: @jagrg (files (directory-files-recursively dir "." nil "^\\([^#.~]\\)"))) -> result: let: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 3), 4

Comment: You're exceeding the number of arguments. Remove the last one. I would also suggest enabling eldoc-mode. It shows you the arglist in the minibuffer. My other solution involves GNU find but I suspect it won't work with Windows.

Comment: @jagrg (files (directory-files-recursively dir "." nil))) - now it' s work. I have one more question. Function "append-file-contents" can append ONLY TEXT files. It's not work with images (e.g. png). Is I'm right?

Comment: You're right. Text files only. Maybe I should edit the function to make it more general. If you're wanting to append image files as well you could probably do it with Org as image [links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-and-tables.html).

Answer (score 4):

One way to get it done is [Shell Commands in Dired](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Commands-in-Dired.html), together with `cat`:

1. Open the directory in dired mode with `C-x d`
2. Mark the desired files with `m`
3. Run a shell command by hitting `!` and typing the command: `cat ? >> /path/to/accumulate-file.txt`

   The `?` surrounded with whitespaces means running the shell command once for each marked files,
   with `?` being replaced by the file name.

Comment: Did you test it with emacs26.1 on Windows 10? Does it work on Windows?

Comment: I get error message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Haven't tested it on Windows yet :( I guess it should work if there is `cat`, it seems I'm wrong from OP's comment. I am trying to do it in elisp way.

Comment: I have added an Elsip solution.

Comment: @Alexei Since you have `cat` as you mentioned in other comment, then I don't understand why this error. Is there any other app "lock" the files? Does `cat` work in Git Bash?

Comment: @whatacold In Git folder has file d:\Programs\Git\usr\bin\cat.exe.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the buffer where you want to insert the files and put point where you want the text to be inserted.
2. Find the directory with the files, i.e., <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>. The directory is shown in a dired buffer.
3. Mark the files with <kbd>m</kbd>.

   a. You can also mark with <kbd>% m</kbd> if you want to select the files by a regular expression.

   b. You can also use <kbd>% g</kbd> if you want to mark files containing matches for a given regular expression.
4. The basic lisp code that provides you with the list of marked files is:

   ```el
   (dired-get-marked-files)
   ```

   The files have the same order as in the dired buffer. You can also sort in other ways with `cl-sort`.
5. Insert files from the list into your target buffer. Therefore run the following lisp code with the dired buffer current:

   ```el
   (dolist (fn (dired-get-marked-files)) (with-current-buffer "target-buffer-name" (insert-file fn)))
   ```

   Note:

   a. You have to replace `"target-buffer-name"` by the name of your target buffer. Often that is the file name of your target file.

   b. For this command to work the buffer with name `"target-buffer-name"` must already exists.

   c. If you want to create a new buffer use `(get-buffer-create "target-buffer-name")` instead.

You can run the elisp expressions in the current buffer easily with the key sequence <kbd>M-:</kbd>. You just input the elisp expression in the minibuffer and run it by pressing the <kbd>RET</kbd> button.

Comment: The docstring of `insert-file` says: `Don’t call it from programs!  Use ‘insert-file-contents’ instead.` , so maybe `insert-file-contents` is better?

Comment: `(dired-get-marked-files)` seem more intuitive to me to get the file lists, and it returns them as in the buffer top-down.

Comment: @whatacold Thanks I will replace `(dired-map-over-marks ...)` by `(dired-get-marked-files)`. I know about `insert-file-contents` and opted for `insert-files` because it works and it is shorter. At this point one just needs the job to be done.

Comment: @whatacold Note that `dired-get-marked-files` is from `dired+.el` which is not necessarily installed. Therefore I will add my original solution again.

Comment: There is `dired-get-marked-files` in dired.el in Emacs 26.1, at least. dired+.el provides another one replacing it, see https://github.com/emacsmirror/dired-plus/blob/master/dired%2B.el#L2498

Comment: @whatacold My bad. Just rolled back the last changes.

Comment: @Tobias In dired mode M-!   Then use command: cat trace* > result.txt . This command copy content of all file with names trace* to ONE file result.txt

Comment: @Alexei You don't need `dired-mode` for that. Just use `M-!` if that works for you. The solution I offered is elisp only and works independently of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

...And then there is the Eshell-way. It uses Elisp under the hood when needed. Therefore it is OS-independent:

1. Open an Eshell via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eshell`.
2. Change directory in the Eshell to the one you want with `cd YourDirectoryPath`.
3. Concatenate all files you want in Eshell with `cat Pattern*Of*Source*Files > targetFile`.

Note, `emacs -Q` uses Elisp for all above steps under Ubuntu (WSL):

```
~ $ which cd
eshell/cd is a compiled Lisp function in ‘em-dirs.el’.
~ $ which cat
eshell/cat is a compiled Lisp function in em-unix.el.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `file1.txt` using `C-x C-f` (`find-file`).  Press `M-!` to execute `shell-command`.  The command you want to execute is [`copy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy):

```
copy /b file1.txt + file2.txt + file2.txt file1.txt
```

Reload the buffer using `M-x revert-buffer` to see that indeed the files were appended.  Beware!  The `copy` command *will* overwrite `file1.txt`.

If you don't have `file1.txt` open, then the `default-directory` will not be for the correct folder.  You would need to either issue `cd` first to change the default directory for the current buffer or use absolute paths.

Comment: In dired mode M-!. Then use command: cat trace* > result.txt . This command copy content of all file with names trace* to ONE file result.txt

Comment: I don't think that default Windows 10 has `cat`.  If you have Gitbash installed, though, then you do and it's likely on the path.  You could use `type`, though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows

Comment: I has Git. As result I has cat on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, as sometimes the crudest of methods is the most appropriate...

1. Open the second file using `C-x C-f` (`find-file`)
2. Select the entire contents using `C-x h` (`mark-whole-buffer`)
3. Copy the text using `M-w` (`kill-ring-save`)
4. Open the first file using `C-x C-f` (`find-file`)
5. Move to the end of the buffer using `M->` (`end-of-buffer`)
6. Paste the text from the first file using `C-y` (`yank`)

At this point, you could save over the original first file using `C-x C-s` (`save-file`) or save a copy using `C-x C-w` (`write-file`).  Repeat this as needed for all the files.

Comment: In folder I has 50 files. So I don't want to repeat 6 steps 50 times!

Comment: And why not!? ;)

Comment: "mark-whole-buffer" The problem that this 50 files are large. So mark whole buffer is very slow and maybe not work correct.

Comment: By "cat" command I can add to one file content of all e.g. java files in current folder and all subfolders like this:  find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec cat {} \; > result.txt