# How search text which is on two lines?

Tags: occur

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10

If I want to show all lines content text in one line I use command `occur`

`M-x occur` **text_to_find**

Nice. It's work fine.

But how I can use `occur`if text to find is on 2 lines?

E.g.:

```
aaa bb cccc
test this text_to_find hello how I your?
result is very good
ddd eee ffff
```

[image]

So I need to show all lines content the next text (in 2 lines)

**text_to_find**

**result**

Comment: Is the line containing `result` must be right after the `text_to_find` line, or do you just want to search two keywords at the same time( use `\(text_to_find\|result\)` as regexp pattern in this case)?

Comment: No. The word "result" is NOT right after the text_to_find. It's after some words on the the NEXT line.

Comment: @whatacold I updated my post

Comment: In connection with [your question about copying multiple files into one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47687/how-to-append-contents-of-multiple-files-into-one-file) maybe [elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) is the right tool for you. It searches multiple files for matches of regular expressions. It also provides the command `elgrep-menu` where you are guided by a menu and have control over almost all options of elgrep.

Comment: Note that there are also other tools that search multiple files such as [`multi-occur`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a literal <kbd>C-j</kbd> to match the newline, which you can etnter by prefixing it with <kbd>C-q</kbd>, i.e.

`M-x occur RET
text-to-find.*C-qC-j.*result`

(occur also takes a prefix argument that tells it how many lines of context to show, which can be useful too).

Comment: "occur also takes a prefix argument that tells it how many lines of context to show, which can be useful too" - it's very cool. Thanks